# Read assembly in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, assemblies

I am using asp.net with C#.
I have a application deployed on the server [published], now I want to see the code for that website, As far as I know I can read assembly to see the code.

please let me know how to acheive it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the RedGate [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to decompile assemblies - it reconstructs the code as best it can. Gets pretty close.

Comment: @Bugz R us - ILDasm will show the IL, not reconstructed C#/VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

Reflector is the best choice if you just need to see the code. If you need to write a program that can read the code, I recommend the [Common Compiler Infrastructure](http://cciast.codeplex.com/).